# Prove or disprove: a ring with unity such that $(xy)^3=x^3y^3$ for all $x, y\in R$ is commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Prove or disprove: A ring with unity, $R$, such that $(xy)^3=x^3y^3$ is a commutative ring.

I was asked to prove this statement.

The identity implies that $(x+1)^3y^3=((x+1)y)^3$ and similarly that
$x^3(y+1)^3=(x(y+1))^3$, but I am stuck here. 
I would like to request help with this problem.

Comment: Please type your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Moreover, please provide more details, for instance, what are your thoughts about the question, what you have tried, where you are stuck. Further, it is unclear what you are trying to ask.

Comment: This is quite difficult to read, alas.

Answer (score 3):

There exist noncommutative rings satisfying $\forall x\forall y((xy)^3=x^3y^3)$.

Background: Let $\varepsilon_k$ denote the identity $(xy)^k=x^ky^k$.

1. Herstein proved in 1961 that if $R$ satisfies $\varepsilon_k$ for some $k>1$, then $R$ has a nil ideal $N$ such that $R/N$ is commutative.
2. Johnsen, Outcalt and Yaqub proved in 1968 that if $R$ satisfies $(xy)^2=x^2y^2$ (i.e. $\varepsilon_2$), then $R$ must be commutative, BUT for every $k>2$ there is a **noncommutative** ring $R_k$ satisfying $(xy)^k=x^ky^k$.
3. Ligh and Richoux proved in 1977 that $R$ is commutative if and only if it satisfies three consecutive $\varepsilon_k$'s. That means $\varepsilon_k, \varepsilon_{k+1}$, and $\varepsilon_{k+2}$ are satisfied for some $k$. It had been proved by Luh in 1971 that satisfying two consecutive $\varepsilon_k$'s is not enough to force commutativity.

Let me describe the example of Johnsen, Outcalt, and Yaqub of a noncommutative ring $R$ satisfying $\varepsilon_3: \;(xy)^3=x^3y^3$. This ring is isomorphic to Luh's example of a noncommutative ring satisfying **both $\varepsilon_3$ and** $\varepsilon_4$.

Let $\mathbb F_3$ be the $3$-element field, and let $R$ be the subring of $M_3(\mathbb F_3)$ consisting of all matrices of the form

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
a&b&c\\
0&a&d\\
0&0&a
\end{array}
\right].
$$ 
Such a matrix may be written $aI+N$ where $N$ is strictly upper triangular.
Since the characteristic is $3$ and since $aI$ commutes with $N$ it follows that $(aI+N)^3 = (aI)^3+N^3 = a^3I$. Using this description of cubes it is easy to verify that $\varepsilon_3$ holds: $((aI+N)(a'I+N'))^3=(aa')^3I=(aI+N)^3(a'+N')^3$. It can be shown that this ring also satisfies $\varepsilon_4$ using $(aI+N)^4=(aI+N)^3(aI+N)=a^3(aI+N)$.